# What happened to the links to import or export a View?

Tags: views, 8, importing-exporting

In Drupal version 7, within the overview of all [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) available in a site (located at "`admin/structure/views`"), for each view there are these options (links) at the very right after each view:

- Enable (if view is disabled) or Disable (if view enabled).
- Edit.
- Delete.
- Clone.
- **Export**.

And near the top there is also an "**import**" link.

However, in Drupal version 8, on the equivalent page (also at "`admin/structure/views`"), there is no more link like **export** or **import**.

So what happened to importing/exporting of a view in D8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That Views import/export facility is **no longer available in Drupal version 8** (within "`admin/structure/views`") ...

A possible way to do similar Views imports/exports in Drupal version 8 is to use the new configuration management facilities, which can typically be used to migrate configuration items, such as Views, between **related** dev, staging and production sites.

So it appears to me that as of right now (8.0.5) there is no "***easy***" way (as it used to be in Drupal version 7) to do such imports/exports between 2 sites that are not "related". Except probably/maybe with some special manual editing to make the site Ids match somehow.

Though according to [Berdir](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/31/berdir)'s comment below (excl. some typos), "***that's not true. You can use single import/export of any configuration file between any site, as long as you take care of the dependencies as well. The related site/UUID checks only apply to a whole config sync.***". And followed by the `/admin/config/development/configuration/single/import` suggestion (merci Berdir).

Maybe an opportunity for a new D8 contributed module to bring this import/export facility back ... and/or one of the "*reasons to be*" for the Features module in D8 (as suggested in another comment by [Danny Englander](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/697/danny-englander)) (merci Danny).

PS: For some more info about `/admin/config/development/configuration/single/import` mentioned above, refer to the Community documentation about "[Managing configuration in Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/administer/config)". Part of what is included on that page is like so (bold markup added here):

> It is possible to export a single configuration file and paste it into another **environment**. The single import option lets you specify the type of the configuration file and import it from your copy-pasted value.

Though nowhere on that page I could find an indication if using "environments" for which site Ids are different (for "single" imports) is allowed or not.

If you want to get an idea of how it is like to use these import/export features, then have a look at the slideshow "[The Magic of Drupal 8’s Configuration Management on a Managed Workflow](http://www.drupalnights.org/sites/g/files/g1416751/f/events/Drupal%208%20CMI%20on%20a%20Managed%20Workflow-%20Drupalcon%20Barcelona.pdf)" (especially slides like on page 44 to 48).

Comment: That's not true. You can use single import/export of *any* configuration file between any site, as long as you take care of the dependencies as well. The related site/UUID checks only apple to a while config sync.

Comment: @Berdir where is the import/export button in D8?

Comment: I'm really liking the Features module for D8, it really puts a nice interface on keeping any kind of config in code / version control including Views.

Comment: @NoSssweat: Here: http://d8/admin/config/development/configuration/single/import

Comment: @Berdir WOW that's really awesome, you can export/import pretty much anything, sick.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install [Configuration Manager module](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_update) .
Then, go to **admin/config/development/configuration/single/export** and get your yml file.

Comment: Looking at the [available releases](https://www.drupal.org/project/configuration/releases) of the module you linked to, I cannot find any release for D8. Am I missing something?

Comment: sorry, here is the right link https://www.drupal.org/project/config_update